# How to Add Custom authentication in feathersjs authentication with SHA256 for Password

Tags: node.js, authentication, bcrypt, sha256, feathersjs

I notice that Feathersjs authentication using bcrypt for password.

This is the code in hooks.js

```
const { authenticate } = require('@feathersjs/authentication').hooks;

const {
  hashPassword, protect
} = require('@feathersjs/authentication-local').hooks;


module.exports = {
  before: {
    all: [],
    find: [ authenticate('jwt') ],
    get: [ authenticate('jwt') ],
    create: [ hashPassword() ],
    update: [ hashPassword(),  authenticate('jwt') ],
    patch: [ hashPassword(),  authenticate('jwt') ],
    remove: [ authenticate('jwt') ]
  },

  after: {
    all: [ 
      // Make sure the password field is never sent to the client
      // Always must be the last hook
      protect('password')
    ],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  },

  error: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  }
};
```

Now I want to change the default hashpassword to sha256, not bycrpt. Does anyone have the solution?

Thanks

Comment: I recommend you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54435194/1235935

Comment: thanks for the info, now i wonder how i can implement this custom func in feathers

Comment: There are already libraries available that implements these algo. Add them to your project and call them from your custom function